# String json to elasticSearch SearchResponse object?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

I have json response from elasticsearch rest client. I would like to create elasticsearch SearchResponse or GetResponse object from that string(json), so that I can reuse un-marshaling part from the grails-2.4.3 elasticsearch plugin.Can some one help me on that ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this question is still relevant, but this one worked for me:

```
String responseJson = "{\"took\":5,\"timed_out\":false,\"_shards\".....}";
try {
  JsonXContentParser xContentParser = new JsonXContentParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY,
  new JsonFactory().createParser(responseJson));      
  SearchResponse response = SearchResponse.fromXContent(xContentParser);
  ... 
  Do Whatever
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  handleException....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to find something that may help you.

I wrote an JSON like this:

```
XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
response.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
String result = Strings.toString(builder);
```

and then I manged to read it like this:

```
 try {
     NamedXContentRegistry registry = new NamedXContentRegistry(getDefaultNamedXContents());
     XContentParser parser = JsonXContent.jsonXContent.createParser(registry, DeprecationHandler.THROW_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, result);
     SearchResponse searchResponse = SearchResponse.fromXContent(parser);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("exception " + e);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("exception " + e);
 }

public static List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> getDefaultNamedXContents() {
    Map<String, ContextParser<Object, ? extends Aggregation>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(TopHitsAggregationBuilder.NAME, (p, c) -> ParsedTopHits.fromXContent(p, (String) c));
    map.put(StringTerms.NAME, (p, c) -> ParsedStringTerms.fromXContent(p, (String) c));
    List<NamedXContentRegistry.Entry> entries = map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new NamedXContentRegistry.Entry(Aggregation.class, new ParseField(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return entries;
}
```

Hope it works :)